# bash short by two columns

Tags: bash, sorting, numerical

I've this dataset:

```
12363 111111
12363 222222
12363 3456
12364 2895
12364 257363
12364 246291
12364 243701
12364 243699
```

I would like to sort this by first column, numerical value, reverse and by second column, numerical value, reverse. Result would be:

```
12364 257363
12364 246291
12364 243701
12364 243699
12364 2895
12363 222222
12363 111111
12363 3456
```

I tried,

```
sort -rn
sort -rnk1,2
sort -rg
sort -rgk1,2
```

But somehow all of these gives back for the second column a wrong order (not numerical, but  values):

```
12364 2895
12364 257363
12364 246291
12364 243701
12364 243699
12363 3456
12363 222222
12363 111111
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
$ sort -rn -k1 -k2 file
12364 257363
12364 246291
12364 243701
12364 243699
12364 2895
12363 222222
12363 111111
12363 3456
```

Note that `-k1 -k2` is not the same as `-k1,2`.